# XCode: Which folder is considered the root?

Tags: xcode

Very newbish question, but which is considered the root of an xcode project. The folder that contains the .xcodeproj file, or the one containing the class files?

I know I'm supposed to put the launch images in the root - but I don't know which that is.

Answer (score 3):

**Those Resources Can Go Anywhere**

You can put the launch images anywhere actually. As long as they're added to the application's target they will be copied over into the application ***bundle***, as part of the "copy files" ^***build phase***.

**Root is at the very top, not the top of where classes go (there can be more than one such directory)**

The root of the project is the directory that contains the .xcodeproj "file". . . Actually this is not just a file, but a directory - you can right-click and choose ***view package contents***.

. . . And the *project.pbxproj* within this directory is a serialized [*plist*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list) in legacy OpenStep format. If you wanted, you could read it into an NSDictionary using:

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: ]
```

. . which is how [CocoaPods](http://www.cocoapods.org/) and similar open-source IDE utilities do their magic.

**^Project Build Phases**

When you choose build Xcode invokes the standard build phases, this incldues:

- Compiling
- Linking
- Copying bundle resources

. . you can view the build phases by clicking on your target and selecting the Build Phases tab. (See pic). You can also add in your own steps here, as part of the build.

[image: Build Phases]